# Prices in week to reflect Drupal 6 version

Tags: javascript, datetime

I'm in the process of rebuilding a site - upgrading from Drupal 6 to 7. The old site uses Availability Calendars, utilizing the weekly price display, which is a necessity (administrative and simplicity). However, when using the Drupal 7 version, the weekly price field functionality has been removed. Are there any iterations of the module that can match exactly the same as the Drupal 6 version?

Comment: Welcome to Drupal Answers! What do you mean by _iterations of the module_?